# How to sort by line only, NOT by line and/or space in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11

I've created a program to sort everything in a text file in alphabetical order. However if 2 or more words on the same line have a space between them it will recognize them as being separate. I want to prevent this.

I'm trying to make it ONLY sort lines. So for example:

> Orange Soda
>
> Pepsi
>
> Coca Cola

*to become......*

> Coca Cola
>
> Orange Soda
>
> Pepsi

*NOT......*

> Coca
>
> Cola
>
> Orange
>
> Pepsi
>
> Soda

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream sortFile("list.txt");
    string theArray[9999], temp;
    int count=0, x, y;

    if(!sortFile.is_open()){
        cout << "Cannot find \"list.txt\" in the current directory." << endl;
    }

    // determine how many separate list items
    while(!sortFile.eof()){
        sortFile >> theArray[count];
        count++;
    }// while

    // arrange array in alphabetical order
    for(x=0;x<count;x++){
        for(y=0;y<count;y++){
            if(theArray[x]<theArray[y]){
                temp = theArray[x];
                theArray[x] = theArray[y];
                theArray[y] = temp;
            }// if
        }// for y
    }// for x

    // save to file
    ofstream saveFile("fixed.txt");
    for(x=0;x<count;x++){
        if(theArray[x]!=theArray[x+1]){
            if(count-1==x){
                saveFile << theArray[x];
            }else{
                saveFile << theArray[x] << endl;
            }// if else
        }else{
            saveFile << theArray[x] << " ";
        }// if else
    }// for

    saveFile.close();
    cout << "Completed Sucessfully! Look for a file named \"fixed.txt\"";

    cin.get();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `std::istream::eof` and use `std::getline` instead of `operator>>`. These go in the loop condition. Also, try `std::vector<std::string>` instead of an array. Even more, you're reimplementing `std::string`'s `operator<` and `std::swap` in your sorting loops. I'll stop here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to this language. Could you be more specific about what to change. I don't see istream::eof. I know this is noob level.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `while` loop with this:

```
while(std::getline(sortFile, theArray[count++]));
```

The `>>` operator for streams delimits at white space, but `getline` will read the whole line.

Additionally, [using eof in a loop condition is Bad<sup>TM</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thank you.